# How to passing result of http request inside async in ExpressJS?

Tags: express, https, async-await

I have below code

```
async send(user, data) {
const postData = {
    'data': 'john',
    'secret': 'secret'
};
const dataJson = JSON.stringify(postData);
const options = {
    hostname: 'example.com',
    path: '/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': dataJson.length
    }
};
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    let data = '';
    console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Body: ', JSON.parse(data));
    });
}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: ", err.message);
});
req.write(dataJson);
req.end();

//---------------
let postResult = // HERE I WANT TO GET WHAT HTTP POST REQUESTED (e.g dataJson.body?)
//---------------

let result;
try {
    result = await this.users.collection('users').updateOne(
        {
            _id: user
        },
        {
            $set: {
                // I WANT TO USE THAT HERE
                data1 : postResult,
                data2 : data2
            }
        },
        { maxTimeMS: consts.DB_MAX_TIME_USERS }
    );
} catch (err) {
    log.error('DB', 'UPDATEFAIL id=%s error=%s', user, err.message);
    err.message = 'Database Error, failed to update user';
    err.code = 'InternalDatabaseError';
    throw err;
}
return { success: true };
}
```

How to get those data to outside variable?

I almost crazy about this, been searching on google and not found anything

I am using express and native-http to make http request, are there any native-curl maybe?

thank you very much for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is using callback to retrieve result, so you can initiate data variable to outside callback function

```
let data = '';
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Body: ', JSON.parse(data));
  });
})
```

And also there are other easier way to make http request with nodejs. you can check [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) that support Promise and async/await.

you can use syntax like this with axios

```
const response = await axios.get('/user?ID=12345');
```

way more easier.